# Java SE, common way to prompt the user to get/set configuration properties

Tags: java

I have to store some user configuration properties.
It is certain that the Preference API is the best way to do so.

I wonder though if there is a "stardard" way, such as a library or a best practice, to actually prompt the user (at least for command line applications) to set or get one or more of those properties.

**Update**

What I have in mind is something that once you have specified the property names and types, you get a "user configuration tool" working out of the box, does something like that already exists?

Comment: For command line arguments check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200054/java-library-for-parsing-command-line-parameters

Comment: It's not exactly what I am looking for, I am not looking for a way to parse command line arguments but a way to prompt the user to the settings he can manage. What I have in mind is something that once you have specified the property names and types, you get a "user configuration tool" working out of the box, does something like that already exists?

Comment: don't know if it is what u are looking for but how about using a simple xml file for the configuration and then use a library like http://xstream.codehaus.org/ to map between xml and a java object containing the config.

Comment: @Dirk, If I have to implement it myself I would probably use the Preference API, as I said. I am looking for an existing library that does the work out of the box.